# CALayer breaks in landscape mode

Tags: ios, calayer, transition

I am coding a custom transition based on the Shutter transition tutorial. it's pretty  simple, the first view controller is meant to divide into hundreds of pieces and then fade one at a time, problem however is that it doesn't work in landscape mode. apparently the "contentsRect" method of CALayer (which is supposed to work on the normalized image space) only works in the portrait mode. I have attached my file in here if anyone needs to have a look and please if you can help me.

http://tinyurl.com/88669oy

regards

here is also my trans code:

```
CALayer*        viewLayer;

- (void)transitWithImageView:(UIImageView *)imgView inView:(UIView *)view withImage:(UIImage *)img
{
     viewLayer = [imgView layer];
    [view.layer addSublayer:viewLayer];


    CGSize layerSize = viewLayer.bounds.size;


    // BEGINING OF MAKE ARRAY OF TRANSITIONS
    NSMutableArray* allTransitionsArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
       for ( int i = 0; i < BLOCK_COUNT; i++ )
    {
        CABasicAnimation *fade = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
        fade.toValue =   [NSNumber numberWithFloat:-1-sqrt(i)];
        fade.autoreverses = NO;
        fade.duration = DURATION;
        [allTransitionsArr addObject: fade];
    }
    // END OF MAKE ARRAY OF TRANSITIONS



    NSMutableArray *blocks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];     
    [viewLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
        [CATransaction begin];

    [CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^(void) 
     {
         [blocks enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) 
          {
              [obj setDelegate:nil];
              [obj removeFromSuperlayer];
          }];
         [view.layer addSublayer:viewLayer];
     }];

    CGFloat bandWidth   = layerSize.width / sqrt(BLOCK_COUNT);
    CGFloat bandHeight  = layerSize.height / sqrt(BLOCK_COUNT);


    int yVal = -1;
     for(int i = 0; i < BLOCK_COUNT; i++)
    {
        CALayer *block = [[CALayer alloc] init];
        block.masksToBounds = YES;
        CGFloat xOffset = 1.f / sqrt(BLOCK_COUNT);
        CGFloat yOffset = 1.f / sqrt(BLOCK_COUNT);
        block.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, bandWidth, bandHeight);
        block.bounds = CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, bandWidth, bandHeight);
        block.contents = (id)[img CGImage];
        block.contentsGravity = kCAGravityCenter;

        CGPoint bandOrigin = viewLayer.frame.origin;
        bandOrigin.x = bandOrigin.x + (bandWidth * (i % (int)sqrt(BLOCK_COUNT)));

        if (i % (int)sqrt(BLOCK_COUNT) == 0 )
            yVal++;

        bandOrigin.y = bandOrigin.y + (bandHeight * yVal);

        // PROBLEM IS GOT TO BE HERE
        block.contentsRect = CGRectMake(xOffset * (i % (int)sqrt(BLOCK_COUNT)) ,yOffset * yVal, xOffset, yOffset);

        [block setValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:bandOrigin] forKeyPath:@"frame.origin"];

        [view.layer addSublayer:block];
        [block addAnimation:[allTransitionsArr objectAtIndex: BLOCK_COUNT - i - 1] forKey:nil];
        [blocks addObject:block];
        [block release];
    }
    [CATransaction commit];
    [blocks release];
}
```